# redirect to another folder in same domain with same query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect users to different directory in same domain but query string in the url needs to remain.

For example, when the user hits

```
 http://selfservice.mycompany.com/Directory1/UpdateUser.aspx?CASE_ID=00001
```

he has to be redirected to

```
 http://selfservice.mycompany.com/customfolder/Directory1/UpdateUser.aspx?CASE_ID=00001
```

My Rewrite Rule is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/Directory1/UpdateUser.aspx?(.*) http://selfservice.mycompany.com/customfolder/Directory1/UpdateUser.aspx?$1
```

But this rule is not working. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in **`/Directory1/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^UpdateUser\.aspx$ /customfolder/Directory1/UpdateUser.aspx [L,QSA,NC,R=302]
```

Query string is automatically carried over to target URL.

Comment: thanks.. looks like it is working. let me move this change to higher environments and confirm.